# Facebook access token in database trigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing a database trigger. So, is there a way to retrieve the facebook access token of the user who is triggering without storing it in database after the user signs in with facebook on android app?

Comment: If you are using Oauh or SocialAuth it returns the access token after sign in with Facebook.

Comment: how to retrieve that in functions?

Comment: Which library you are using.?

Comment: Nope, MySQL triggers can't make http requests.

Comment: Likely answer below. If that's not what you're looking for, please update your question to provide more information on the context. Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on this most effective way to get help with code-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase documentation on Realtime Database triggered Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#accessing_user_authentication_information):

> From `EventContext.auth` and `EventContext.authType`, you can access the user information, including permissions, for the user that triggered a function. This can be useful for enforcing security rules, allowing your function to complete different operations based on the user's level of permissions:
>
> ```
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
> const admin = require('firebase-admin');
>
> exports.simpleDbFunction = functions.database.ref('/path')
>     .onCreate((snap, context) => {
>       if (context.authType === 'ADMIN') {
>         // do something
>       } else if (context.authType === 'USER') {
>         console.log(snap.val(), 'written by', context.auth.uid);
>       }
>     });
> ```